# Concatenating more than 1 Authors using CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a sub query that gets the top author by first name but since there can be more than 1 author, I want to concatenate the authors by ",". Would I need to use a case statement to check if there are more than 1 authors and then get the authors. How would I do that exactly?

The following is the subquery used to get the 1st top author:

```
Select p.pubdate, p.pccity,
 (SELECT TOP (1) con.FirstName+' '+con.LastName from PrCrew pc 
left join Positions pos on pos.ID=pc.Position
left join Contacts con on con.ID=pc.Contact
where pc.Production=p.ID and pc.Position='2' ORDER BY con.FirstName DESC )as [Author]

from Productions p
left join C c on c.Username=p.CS
left join Off o on o.Code=p.off
```

Comment: show sample data or better provide sql fiddle link...?